# Changing Grid Column Heading Name in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

In the Create Purchase Order Screen, I have added four fields, Product Manager, Product Manager Name, a User Defined field (Buyer ID) and the Buyer Name in the grid to be displayed. These fields come from the Stock Item Screen).

I want to change the Heading column Employee Name to Product Manager Name in the Grid shown.

PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName(cache, "_____", "Product Manager Name");

How exactly it has to be done. Where do I put the code ??

Answer (score 3):

I would add the SetDisplayName call to a graph extension on that graph in the override of initialize. Here is a working example below using existing fields:

```
public class POCreateExtension : PXGraphExtension<POCreate>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<POFixedDemand.vendorID>(Base.Caches[typeof(POFixedDemand)], "kung fu panda");
    }
}
```

Comment: The Vendor ID gets changed but the field Employee Name does not appear in the DAC and hence is not found. How to refer it ??

Comment: The Product Manager ID for the InventoryItem also gets changed. I tried getting the EPEmployee.acctName but that also does not display change in the Grid Header.

Comment: You might have to add a dummy view to those or add a cache entry. For example add view property "public PXSelect<EPEmployee> employees;" to the graph extension and see if changing the display name for acctName works?

Comment: I see what you are asking now... The column is using data field "InventoryItem__ProductManagerID_EPEmployee_acctName" and you want to change "Employee Name" to a different value. I had a similar need on another page for the same ProductManagerID field and could never find a resolution. Sorry i could not be more helpful